# How to simulate properly the heating system example in modelica fluid library?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

Openmodelica newbie here.

I'm trying to get my head around modelica fluid and thermal libraries, but I keep running into lots of errors while trying to simulate the examples that are already inside those library.
More specifically I cannot find a way to simulate correctly the Heating System example under the modelica fluid library.

The log shows some errors in the radiator part, while computing the status at t=0 :

division leads to inf or nan at time 0, (a=110007) / (b=0), where divisor b is: radiator.mediums[1].d
solver will try to handle division by zero at time 0: radiator.mediums[1].d * radiator.crossAreas[1] * radiator.nParallel

I could understand that the problem relies in the radiator.mediums[1].d but there's no way to act on it as it is part of the library itself (dynamic pipe element).
Searching the web, I found that the same exact problem showed in previous modelica releases, but I'm using both the latest versione of Connection Editor and modelica library.

Has anyone got any advice?

Using OpenModelica 1.21 64 bit on a Windows 10 machine. Modelica standard library and services 4.0 installed through openmodelica installer.

Thanks

Comment: You mean 'Modelica.Fluid.Examples.HeatingSystem', right? Assuming it is unmodified that seems like an issue in the OpenModelica version you are using so you should include the full information about which version you are using.

Comment: Exactly, unmodified example with predefined simulation setup. I am using OpenModelica 1.21 64 bit on a windows 10 machine. Modelica standard library 4.0